# SQL Searching for Unique Column based on a set of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I am new to SQL and run into a problem. Firstly to describe what I am trying to do. I have a select query to join 3 tables to end up with data that gives me a set of esx hosts in various  clusters and the VLAN trunks each vmnic on a host sees. Now I need to go through this list and find each host in a cluster that have vmnics that don't match the others, as we want the vLAN trunk to be matching on vmnics on all hosts in a particular cluster. To give an example of my results after I run my query -

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|  Cluster  |  Host  |  VMNIC  |  VLAN_TRUNK               |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  clst001  | c1hst1 | vmnic01 |  401 501-505 508 709 1505 |
|  clst001  | c1hst1 | vmnic02 |  401 501-505 709          |
|  clst001  | c1hst1 | vmnic03 |  401 501-505 508 709 1505 |
|  clst001  | c1hst2 | vmnic01 |  401 501-505 508 709 1505 |
|  clst001  | c1hst2 | vmnic02 |  401 501-505 508 709 1505 |
|  clst001  | c1hst2 | vmnic03 |  401 501-505 508 709 1505 |
|  clst001  | c1hst3 | vmnic01 |  401 501-505 508 709 1505 |    
|  clst001  | c1hst3 | vmnic02 |  401 501-505 508 709 1505 |
|  clst001  | c1hst3 | vmnic03 |  401 501-505 508 709 1505 |
|  clst002  | c2hst1 | vmnic01 |  408 501-505 522 701 1555 |
|  clst002  | c2hst1 | vmnic04 |  408 501-505 522 701 1555 |
|  clst002  | c2hst1 | vmnic05 |  408 501-505 522 701 1555 |
|  clst002  | c2hst2 | vmnic01 |  408 501-505 522 701 1555 |
|  clst002  | c2hst2 | vmnic04 |  408 501-505 701 1555     |
|  clst002  | c2hst2 | vmnic05 |  408 501-505 522 701 1555 |
|  clst002  | c2hst3 | vmnic01 |  408 501-505 522 701 1555 |
|  clst002  | c2hst3 | vmnic04 |  408 501-505              |
|  clst002  | c2hst3 | vmnic05 |  408 501-505 522 701 1555 |
|  clst003  | c3hst1 | vmnic01 |  505 622 745              |
|  clst003  | c3hst1 | vmnic02 |  505 622 745              |
|  clst003  | c3hst2 | vmnic01 |  505 622 745              |
|  clst003  | c3hst2 | vmnic02 |  505 622 745              |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please note that I built the above depiction using a text editor, to give a visual illustration of what I see.

What I am hoping to achieve  is to be able to identify the unique VLAN_TRUNK based on the cluster and the Host. For example, I want to identify from the above table that problematic hosts vlans in each cluster and host are -

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|  Cluster  |  Host  |  VMNIC  |  VLAN_TRUNK               |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  clst001  | c1hst1 | vmnic02 |  401 501-505 709          |
|  clst002  | c2hst2 | vmnic04 |  408 501-505 701 1555     |
|  clst002  | c2hst3 | vmnic04 |  408 501-505              |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have around 4000 such rows, and about 100 clusters, each with varying number of hosts and vmnics.

I have tried using the count, distinct function but this doesn't work well for me. It's difficult for me to post the query as this site is blocked at work, so I am posting this from home. If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to tackle this, it will be much appreciated!

Comment: if you really want an answer post example code on sql fiddle 
for example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/412f0/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really **should** show what it is you've tried so far, but assuming I understand your question right, it can be done with COUNT.

Here is an example given the data you provided. Take a look at the SQL statement and you'll see how the `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` is performed on the columns of interest. We then limit it to those that have a `COUNT` of 1 to get a "distinct" listing.

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE (Cluster VARCHAR(20),  Host VARCHAR(20),  VMNIC VARCHAR(20), VLAN_TRUNK  VARCHAR(200))             

INSERT INTO @Data (Cluster, Host, VMNIC, VLAN_TRUNK)
VALUES 

('clst001', 'c1hst1', 'vmnic01', '401 501-505 508 709 1505'),
('clst001', 'c1hst1', 'vmnic02', '401 501-505 709'),
('clst001', 'c1hst1', 'vmnic03', '401 501-505 508 709 1505'),
('clst001', 'c1hst2', 'vmnic01', '401 501-505 508 709 1505'),
('clst001', 'c1hst2', 'vmnic02', '401 501-505 508 709 1505'),
('clst001', 'c1hst2', 'vmnic03', '401 501-505 508 709 1505'),
('clst001', 'c1hst3', 'vmnic01', '401 501-505 508 709 1505'),    
('clst001', 'c1hst3', 'vmnic02', '401 501-505 508 709 1505'),
('clst001', 'c1hst3', 'vmnic03', '401 501-505 508 709 1505'),
('clst002', 'c2hst1', 'vmnic01', '408 501-505 522 701 1555'),
('clst002', 'c2hst1', 'vmnic04', '408 501-505 522 701 1555'),
('clst002', 'c2hst1', 'vmnic05', '408 501-505 522 701 1555'),
('clst002', 'c2hst2', 'vmnic01', '408 501-505 522 701 1555'),
('clst002', 'c2hst2', 'vmnic04', '408 501-505 701 1555'),
('clst002', 'c2hst2', 'vmnic05', '408 501-505 522 701 1555'),
('clst002', 'c2hst3', 'vmnic01', '408 501-505 522 701 1555'),
('clst002', 'c2hst3', 'vmnic04', '408 501-505'),
('clst002', 'c2hst3', 'vmnic05', '408 501-505 522 701 1555'),
('clst003', 'c3hst1', 'vmnic01', '505 622 745'),
('clst003', 'c3hst1', 'vmnic02', '505 622 745'),
('clst003', 'c3hst2', 'vmnic01', '505 622 745'),
('clst003', 'c3hst2', 'vmnic02', '505 622 745')


SELECT Cluster, Host, VLAN_TRUNK, COUNT(*) Cnt
  FROM @Data
GROUP BY Cluster, Host, VLAN_TRUNK
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use the sql fiddler example above to show what I tried later tonight.

Comment: Hello Mr Moose, Thanks, I am one step closer! previously I was doing the following, which wasn't working - `SELECT Cluster, Host, VLAN_TRUNK, Count(Distinct VLAN_TRUNK) from @Data GROUP BY Cluster, Host, VLAN_TRUNK `I have tried your way, and it identifies the mismatches, however in the clusters, where two nics are missing vlans but are the same as each other, it doesn't get picked up. How can I identify such a condition? if not I can comprise and just identify the cluster that has a mismatch and go and manually identify the host

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'two nics are missing vlans'. If it is simply that for a given cluster, host, vmnic combination, it has a null or blank vlan, then, simply write a query for that. By that I mean, look for that combination that has no other results other than blanks or nulls.